# how to set jsf welcome page with request param

Tags: html, jsf, web.xml

I want to use this as the welcome page for my JSF Java EE 8 web application

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>channel.xhtml?handle=mehdi</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

However it shows me the 404 custom page I set up. I think it looks for a jsf page 
named "channel.xhtml?handle=mehdi".

is there something to replace "?" like in the case of "&" is replaced with `&amp;`

Thanks.

Comment: So you don't get a custom 404 page if you remove the request param?

Comment: without it, it works. However the parameter is essential (like a youtube video link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by creating a new page called `home.xhtml` where I use

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{channelBean.setupHome()}"></f:viewAction>
</f:metadata>
```

in `setupHome()` I set the parameter.